# Oracle Database 11g Express: Error using Data Pump Export

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, expdp

I want to export a DB, first I use the cmd

```
C:\>expdp userid=AF/AF@//214.146.74.241:1521/LOPES CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY dumpfile=lopes.dmp
```

with the result

```
La tabla maestra "AF"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_03" se ha cargado/descargado correctamente
******************************************************************************
El juego de archivos de volcado para AF.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_03 es:
  C:\ORACLE\ADMIN\LOPES\DPDUMP\LOPES.DMP
El trabajo "AF"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_03" ha terminado correctamente en Mar Sep 26 11:07:25 2017 elapsed 0 00:02:04
```

But this folder does not exists, because the Oracle is located here: `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle` so I can't file the dump file anywhere

Then I tried with:

```
 C:\>expdp userid=AF/AF@//214.146.74.241:1521/LOPES CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY dumpfile=c:/tmp/lopes.dmp
```

With this result:

```
Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Mar Sep 26 11:18:11 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39001: valor de argumento no vßlido
ORA-39000: especificaci≤n de archivo de volcado err≤nea
ORA-39088: el nombre de archivo no puede contener una especificaci≤n de ruta de acceso
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expdp utility creates a dump file on the server in the default directory,directory 'DATA_PUMP_DIR'.

```
 SELECT a.owner, a.directory_name, a.directory_path
 FROM sys.all_directories a
 where directory_name='DATA_PUMP_DIR'
```

The obsolete utility exp creates a dump file on the client in the specified location.

Answer (score 0):

a question of mine would be, did you define the global export directory in your database With dba privileges: CREATE DIRECTORY ExportData AS 'C:\ExportData';

after that you need read / write permissions on this directory object for the user you want to export with expdp GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY ExportData TO YOUR_USER;